# Cumulative Customer Retention

Tags: r

I have a table of customers (cust_id), period & subscription. The ask is to calculate customer retention in a cumulative manner from one period to the other paying attention to customer subscription (sub) when it is 1-active sub or 0-cancelled.

()Period 1 has 1,2,3 unique customers & period 2 has 1,2,4 unique customers, two customers came from period 1 into period 2 and so the retention rate is 2/3 = 0.6667. The denominator been a count of customer (1,2,3) from period 1.
()Period 2 has 1,2,4 and Period 3 has 3,4,5 but customer 1 has stopped their subscription so we are not necessarily expecting to see 1 and also there is customer 3 from period 1 so that retention rate is 1/3 = 0.3333. The denominator been a count of customer (2,4) from period 2 & customer 3 from period 1.
()Period 3 has 3,4,5 and period 4 has 2,3,6 but customer 2 still has their subscription on, so cumulative customer retention is 1/4 = 0.25. The denominator been a count of customer (3,4,5) from period 3 & customer 2 from period 1 who was also in period 2.

**Table**

```
customer_table <- structure(list(cust_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 4, 
                           3, 2, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 4), period = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), Subscription = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("cust_id", "period", "Subscription"
                                                               ), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

  cust_id period Subscription
1        1      1            1
2        2      1            1
3        3      1            1
4        1      1            1
5        4      2            1
6        2      2            1
7        2      2            1
8        1      2            0
9        5      3            1
10       3      3            1
11       3      3            1
12       4      3            1
13       3      4            0
14       2      4            1
15       2      4            1
16       6      4            1
17       5      5            1
18       4      5            1
19       2      5            1
20       4      5            1
```

Code used lacks the cumulative element and also not sure if the exclusion of cancelled subscription has been applied correctly

```
library(dplyr)
customer_table %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
 summarise(retention=length(intersect(cust_id,customer_table$cust_id[customer_table$period==(period+1)]))/n_distinct(cust_id[customer_table$Subscription==1])) %>% 
  mutate(retention=lag(retention))
```

Wrong output

```
  period retention
   <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1     NA   
2      2      0.5 
3      3      0.25
4      4      0.25
5      5      0.25
```

Required output

```
  period retention
   <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1     NA   
2      2      0.666 
3      3      0.33
4      4      0.25
5      5      0.33
```

Comment: Why is there parenthesis in '()Period'?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `cust_id[customer_table$Subscription==1]` by `cust_id[Subscription==1]` gives results closer to the required output

```r
# THIS IS NOT THE CORRECT SOLUTION, BUT IT'S CLOSER
customer_table %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  summarise(retention= length(intersect(cust_id,.$cust_id[.$period== period+1]))/n_distinct(cust_id[Subscription==1])) %>% 
  mutate(retention=lag(retention))

  period retention
   <int>     <dbl>
1      1    NA    
2      2     0.667
3      3     0.5  
4      4     0.333
5      5     0.5
```

Comment: That's helpful and it takes the code one step closer towards solving the problem. The main issue is how to include the cumulative element that allows the code to pick a customer from a previous period regardless of how far back.

Comment: Which part of the code is it ?

Comment: I am not sure that I understood the problem correctly

Comment: As an example, what the code is currently doing is to compare period 3 against period 2. It then counts the number of intersects and divides it by the number of distinct id in previous 1 (which is the previous period). Where the subscription is cancelled the code removes that id and does not include cancelled id's in the denominator count...

Comment: In addition to the above the problem requires that the code has some sort of memory so as to be able to include unique id's from period 1 that didn't appear in period 2 but still have an active subscription.

Comment: Try a `for` loop, it might be more easy to get the algorithm